# Take the highest bid by this user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm building an auction site and the user can bid on the same item more than once (obviously). In the user's dashboard, a user can view his bids. When the user bids on the same item more than once, I want only **one** entry with the highest bid value to show up. My current code shows an entry for each bid. I tried a few things but I couldn't figure it out. Here's what I've got:

```
public class Bid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

    protected override List<ItemForUserBids> ResolveCore(User source)
    {
        var items = new List<ItemForUserBids>();
        var userBids = source.Bids;
        foreach (var bid in userBids)
        {
            var item = bid.Item;
            var c = new ItemForUserBids
                        {
                            BidValue = bid.Amount,
                            BidId = bid.Id,
                            Description = item.Description,
                            Id = item.Id,
                            ItemThumb = item.MainImageLink(),
                            Status = _itemsService.GetBiddingStatus(item, source),
                            TimeLeft = item.EndDate.TimeLeft(),
                            Title = item.Title
                        };
            items.Add(c);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

I tried to get Distinct bids based on the Item.Id but that did not work. Now I'm thinking maybe I could use the Date property of the Bid entity somehow to get to the result I want but my head stopped thinking.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I got it to work using a dictionary and using OrderBy() and Max() like many suggested. But I think the latter could be further improved.

Implementation using a dictionary (*works*):

```
    var userBids = new Dictionary<string, Bid>();

    foreach (var bid in allUserBids)
    {
        var key = bid.Item.Id.ToString();
        if(userBids.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if (userBids[key].Amount < bid.Amount)
                userBids[key] = bid;
        }
        userBids[key] = bid;
    }
```

Attempt using the other method (*works*):

```
    var highestBids =
        source.Bids.Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Item.Id,
                                            (itemId, bids) =>
                                            new
                                                {
                                                    ItemId = itemId,
                                                    MaxBid = bids.Max(x => x.Amount)
                                                }).ToList();
    var userBids = new List<Bid>();
    foreach (var bid in source.Bids)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < highestBids.Count; i++)
        {
            var curr = highestBids[i];
            if (bid.Item.Id.Equals(curr.ItemId) && bid.Amount.Equals(curr.MaxBid)) {
                userBids.Add(bid);
                highestBids.Remove(curr);
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I get rid of those loops? And maybe have it all in one chained statement?

Comment: Your tags are confusing. To me this question has nothing to do with `asp.net-mvc-3` and `automapper`. It's `entity-framework-4` related about querying your data. So please remove the unnecessary tags.

Comment: Doesn't seem Entity Framework related either. Sounds like a case of don't-know-don't-have-time-to-research-please-fix-my-code.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Done. The reason why I included those is because my application uses those technologies as well as EF4. But I guess you are right, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not a Microsoft person, so don't know how to work this into the framework you're using, but this really doesn't seem like something to do in code -- it would be a really simple database query to get the highest bid from each user for a given item.

Comment: @bzlm: How do you know I did not do enough research? This is definitely not true! You would've been more helpful if you would've atleast provided a hint on where I could get started solving this problem.

Comment: @Kassem Sounds like you just did the wrong Distinct (Item ID instead of User ID). Something more testing would have shown. :)

Comment: Break down the problem, use unit testing.

Comment: @bzlm: But even that wouldn't solve the problem. If I'm going to do `.Distinct()` I need to have the Bid entity implement `IEquatable` which only checks for equal objects based on the criteria I decide. But how can I be sure that it is going to return the one with highest amount?

Comment: @Kassem You need to know how `Distinct` works; specifically how it selects which element to keep. When you know that, you can make it keep the one with the highest amount. Or you need to learn how `GroupBy` works. MSDN is a great source for both of these.

Comment: Why should a user be allowed to make a bid then bid a second time at a lower value? The next bid should always be higher, not lower, so you only need to keep the latest bid, not the highest.

Comment: @MPelle, that's already in the question; "maybe I could use the Date property [...] but my head stopped thinking".

Comment: @MPelletier: Of course a user can only bid a higher bid than the last bid (whether it was his bid or some else's).

Comment: @bzlm: I've updated my question. Could you take a look at it please?

Comment: Ok it works now, it was a silly mistake. But I'd like to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments posted so far should be a good indication that you should look into re-architecting this a little, but the immediate code solution involves using System.Linq to chain together a GroupBy, Max, and a Select.

Comment: Ah makes sense! I think that's more efficient that Sam Holder's suggestion. Will give both a try and see what works for me.

Comment: does this eliminate your loop? `var userBids = source.Bids.Where(x => highestBids.Any(y => y.ItemId == x.Item.Id && x.Amount == y.MaxBid)).ToList();`

Comment: Yup, perfect! So do you think that's the most efficient way of doing it? Or could that be optimized even further?

Comment: It depends on how expensive it is to query your datasource and whether you really need to offload the work into C#; a SQL solution would probably be a lot more efficient.  I wouldn't work on optimizing without actually measuring your application's performance with something like dotTrace or jMeter, I find it generally simpler to focus on architecture and functionality until my codebase is feature complete.

Answer (score 1):

you could simply create a dictionary of user bids, where the key is the item id.  Then for each user bid if an item id is not already used then add the current bid to the dictionary, if it is used then see if the bid amount of the item that exists in the dictionary already is lower than the current item then replace the existing item in the dictionary with the current one.

However this is very inefficient as really you only want to load the top 1 bid sorted descending by bid amount for each bid id, not load all the bids then work out the highest.  What happens if your user has 10,000 old bids?  Do they all get loaded?

Comment: Hmmm... your last remark makes a lot of sense. But then again, I still need to display "old bids" but I guess not ones that are "too old". +1 for the remark. And by the way, I thought about something similar to what you suggested, I just did not think of using a dictionary which will make it much easier :)